# rxjava - how to take alternating emissions from two observables

Tags: rx-java2

I have two observables and i would like to take from each one until there is nothing left from both. is there any operator to do this ? let me show you an example of what i have tried and what i want to accomplish:

```
  Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("hello","are", "doing");
        Observable<String> observable2 = Observable.just("how","you","today");
```

i would like to "reduce" this such that the final emissions would be"
**Hello how are you doing today**

here i have tried using scan but it works more like accumulation and i get the following results:

```
Observable.merge(observable, observable2).reduce(new BiFunction<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String wordAccum1, String word2) {
            return wordAccum1 + " " + word2;
        }

    }).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String sentence) throws Exception {
            Log.v("consumerResult",sentence+"");
        }
    });
```

log output shows:
consumerResult: **hello are doing how you today**

how can i take from each one consecutively ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
    Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("hello", "are", "doing");
    Observable<String> observable2 = Observable.just("how", "you", "today");


    observable.zipWith(observable2, new BiFunction<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String s, String s2) throws Exception {
            return s+" "+s2;
        }
    }).reduce(new BiFunction<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String s, String s2) throws Exception {
            return s+ " " + s2;
        }
    }).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(s); // this will emit with "hello how are you doing today"
        }
    });
```

If you are using Java 8, you can reduce the same code using lambda, as follows

```
 observable.zipWith(observable2, (s, s2) -> s + " " + s2)
            .reduce((s, s2) -> s +" "+ s2).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: The key is `zipWith`. You don't need `scan`+`lastElement`, `reduce` suffices.